# What was implemented on this site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, user-interface

I'm trying to recreate the functionality of this site: http://www.uniqlo.com/jp/supercoolbiz/

I'm wondering how they did a couple things:

1. How do they get it to display a loading... (1%...100%) until the page is fully loaded? That is, how do they get the rest of the site to pop up upon loading, and how do you signal this as an event in javascript?
2. How do they get the divs to wiggle around on hover?
3. How do they get the images to change on hover so fluidly? (When you scroll over a single model, they rotate)

Comment: The site uses flash, not javascript

Comment: The website is based on Flash

Comment: Yeah, there's zero JavaScript used for what you described. It's all Flash. And Flash is compiled, so we can't easily look at it.

Comment: Some quick tips on helping you reverse engineer sites that use JavaScript, though: use Firebug/developer tools on Chrome; and grab the awesome bookmarklet called [VisualEvent](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That site doesn't have any JavaScript as far as I can tell. It looks like it's completely Flash driven. You can always tell by right-clicking in the page. If it's a Flash site, you'll see options geared towards Flash, and there won't be an option to view the source. See the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mate its because it is not done in JS but in Flash :)

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly Flash. You are correct in that jQuery is linked in the `<head>`, but it seems to only do this:

```
if(jQuery.browser.msie && parseInt(jQuery.browser.version) == 6){
wmodetype="transparent";
}
```

Looks to be some sort of browser detection for a specific part of their site. If you look around that snippet, you'll notice that this detection is used for the Flash as well. So, basically, the entire site is Flash.